# Why don't I get numeric values from this Solve?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[ a^2 + b^2 == c^2 && a < 100 && b < 100 && c < 100, {a, b, c}, Integers]
```

gives me this result

> ```
> {{c -> ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[ a^2 + b^2],
>          ((a | b | c) ∈ Integers &&  Sqrt[10000 - a^2] - b > 0  && -99 <= a <= -1) ||
>          ((a | b | c) ∈ Integers &&  Sqrt[10000 - a^2] - b > 0  &&   1 <= a <= 99) || 
>          ((a | b | c) ∈ Integers &&  Sqrt[10000 - a^2] + b <= 0 && -99 <= a <= -1) ||
>          ((a | b | c) ∈ Integers &&  Sqrt[10000 - a^2] + b <= 0 &&   1 <= a <= 99) ||
>               ...           ] },   ...  }
> ```

where I would expect something like

> ```
> {{x -> 3, y -> 4, z -> 5}, {x -> 4, y -> 3, z -> 5}, {x -> 5, y -> 12, z -> 13},...}
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first 1000 of rep! That many more may follow.

Comment: Yeah! congrats!

Comment: @Sjoerd - Whohoo! Party time! :-) Still a long way to [71k](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/2064/stevenvh) I'm afraid :-)

Comment: @stevenvh grats! wow, I did not realize you were leading on electronics - nice score ;)

Comment: @Vitaliy - Thanks. Hey, I'm doing great: another 5 rep, already at 1045!, so 70k by Thanksgiving may be possible after all :-). *I'll have to do a lot of studying on Mathematica until then, I'm afraid.*

Comment: @stevenvh Well, I'm sure Mr.Wizard will substitute you for the turkey if you try to overtake him... ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works (it's obvious the same will hold for negative integers):

```
Reduce[a^2 + b^2 == c^2 && 0 < a < 100 && 0 < b < 100 && 0 < c < 100, {a, b, c}, Integers]
```

[image]

And if you're up for an interesting visualization, here is my take:

```
ListPlot3D[{a, b, c} /. Solve[a^2 + b^2 == c^2 && 0 < a < 100 && 0 < b < 100 && 
    0 < c < 100, {a, b, c}, Integers], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Filling -> Bottom, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Also seems to work with Solve if I include the lower limits of 0. Any reason why I should use `Reduce` instead of `Solve`, other than the different output format? They seem equally fast.

Comment: @stevenvh You may find the link at the end of my answer useful for the question in your comment above

Comment: I can't upvote again, but I like the scaly plot... looks like some exotic fish skeleton. :)

Comment: That plot needs to be on some superhero's chest...

Comment: For `c` given the larger number of solutions the larger grains should be, but they aren't.

Answer (score 6):

Bound the variables from both sides if you want to get explicit results

```
s = Solve[a^2+b^2==c^2&& -100 < a < 100&& -100 < b < 100&& -100 < c < 100, {a,b,c}, Integers]
(* -> {{a -> -99, b -> 0, c -> -99}, {a -> -98, b -> 0, c -> 98} ... *)
ListPointPlot3D[{a, b, c} /. s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you could reduce the domain to positive integers, taken advantage of the problem being quadratic on all vars:

```
s = Solve[a^2 + b^2 - c^2 == 0 && 
      0 <= a < 100 && 0 <= b < 100 &&  0 <= c < 100, {a, b, c}, Integers]

ListPointPlot3D[{a, b, c} /. s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

And you can verify that

```
2 Sum[SquaresR[2, i^2], {i, 0, 99}] -1 == (2 Length@# -Count[#, 0]) &@Flatten[{a, b, c} /. s]
(* True *)
```

[This](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html) is a useful reading when solving Diophantine equations

Answer (score 5):

The result we get is correct and one shouldn't expect it in a different form since there are infinitely many solutions and there is no way to enumerate them all. That's why `Mathematica` returns the result in a symbolic way. This issue appears a bit more obviously when one looks for all solutions in special subclasses, e.g. solutions of this form :

`a == 3k, b == 4k, c == 5k` for `k < 20 && k ∈ Integers`, e.g. `k == -10^100000`. We have to use `Reduce` instead of `Solve` in this case :

```
Reduce[(3 k)^2 + (4 k)^2 == (5 k)^2 && k < 20, k, Integers]
```

> ```
> k ∈ Integers && k <= 19
> ```

There are infinitely many solutions, however if we add a lower bound for `k` we'll get 
a finite numbers of explicit solutions :

```
Reduce[(3 k)^2 + (4 k)^2 == (5 k)^2 && 15 < k < 20, k, Integers]
```

> ```
> k == 16 || k == 17 || k == 18 || k == 19
> ```

Let's visualize an interesting part of the solution space to the general problem :

```
pts = Solve[{ a^2 + b^2 == c^2,
             -300 < a < 100, -300 < b < 100, -300 < c < 100}, {a, b, c}, Integers];
Length[pts]
```

> ```
> 2345
> ```

```
Show[ ContourPlot3D[ x^2 + y^2 == z^2, {x, -300, 100}, {y, -300, 100}, {z, -300, 100}, 
                    ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 20]], 
                    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 7, PlotPoints -> 100], 
      ListPointPlot3D[ {a, b, c} /. pts, PlotStyle -> Directive[Darker@Red, PointSize[0.004]]]]
```

[image]

These cones (the upper and a part of the lower) denote all real solutions  whereas the red points denote all integer sloutions of the sytem : `{ a^2 + b^2 == c^2,
                 -300 < a < 100, -300 < b < 100, -300 < c < 100}`

One might be also interested in integer solutions modulo `100` to find all solutions of this type : `a^2 + b^2 == c^2 + 100 k` for `k ∈ Integers` (i.e. solutions satisfy `0 <= a < 100, 0 <= b < 100, 0 <= c < 100` ), there are many more such solutions ( i.e. `17400`) :

```
Solve[ a^2 + b^2 == c^2, {a, b, c}, Modulus -> 100] // Short[#, 2] &
```

> ```
> {{a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0},  {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 10}, {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 20},
>  {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 30},   <<17393>>,     {a -> 99, b -> 90, c -> 49},
>  {a -> 99, b -> 90, c -> 51}, {a -> 99, b -> 90, c -> 99}}
> ```

Comment: Your cone is too steep. Some points are falling off :)

Comment: @belisarius The solution of this problem is out of the scope of the question :)

Comment: @belisarius Nevertheless I've corrected the plot.

Comment: Ok. I will remove my downvote ;)