# How to plot inequalities taking into account that points must be integers and not reals?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have solved with Mathematica 9 the following integer inequalities using Reduce:

```
eq = Reduce[
  m (k - 1) + (k - 2) == c k && m >= 2 && k >= 2 && c >= 1, {k, m, 
   c}, Integers, Backsubstitution -> True]

(* (k | m | c) \[Element] Integers && k >= 2 && m >= 2 && 
 c == (-2 + k - m + k m)/k *)

better = Reduce[
  m (k - 1) + (k - 2) <  c k && m >= 2 &&  k >= 2 && c >= 1, {k, m, 
   c}, Integers, Backsubstitution -> True]

(* (c \[Element] Integers && k == 2 && m == 2 && 
   c >= 2) || ((m | c) \[Element] Integers && k == 2 && m >= 3 && 
   c > m/2) || ((k | m | c) \[Element] Integers && k >= 3 && m >= 2 &&
    c > (-2 + k - m + k m)/k) *)

worst = Reduce[
  m (k - 1) + (k - 2) >  c k && m >= 2 &&  k >= 2 && c >= 1 , {k, m, 
   c}, Integers, Backsubstitution -> True]

(* ((m | c) \[Element] Integers && k == 2 && m >= 3 && 
   1 <= c < m/2) || ((k | m | c) \[Element] Integers && k >= 3 && 
   m >= 2 && 1 <= c < (-2 + k - m + k m)/k) *)
```

Now I need to plot them. However, using `RegionPlot3D` I can only plot a region made of reals, while the solutions are integers. What is the proper way to plot the solutions when the domain is `Integers` ?

Comment: This answer should be helpful http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10388/why-dont-i-get-numeric-values-from-this-solve/10394#10394

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** you can use your conditions to define the `RegionFunction` in `ListPointPlot3D` without having to use `Reduce`. For example, for the set `better`:

```
 ListPointPlot3D[Tuples[Range[20], 3], ImageSize -> 500,BoxRatios -> 1,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{m, k, c}, 
   m (k - 1) + (k - 2) < c k && m >= 2 && k >= 2 && c >= 1] ]
```

[image]

---

You can use `Graphics3D` or `ListPointPlot3D` using all the integer solutions that lie in the plot range of your choice:

```
dom =0 <= k <= 20 && 0 <= m <= 20 && 0 <= c <= 20; (* this plays the role of PlotRange *)
eq = Last /@ # & /@ {ToRules[
 Reduce[m (k - 1) + (k - 2) == c k && m >= 2 && k >= 2 && c >= 1 && dom,
    {k, m, c}, Integers, Backsubstitution -> True]]};
better = Last /@ # & /@ {ToRules[
  Reduce[m (k - 1) + (k - 2) < c k && m >= 2 && k >= 2 && c >= 1 && dom, 
    {k, m, c}, Integers, Backsubstitution -> True]]};
worse = Last /@ # & /@ {ToRules[
  Reduce[m (k - 1) + (k - 2) > c k && m >= 2 && k >= 2 && c >= 1 && dom,
    {k, m, c}, Integers, Backsubstitution -> True]]};
Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Opacity[.3], Blue, Point@better, Green, 
   Point@worse, Opacity[1], Red, Point@eq}]
```

[image]

```
ListPointPlot3D[{eq, better, worse}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[.02], Red], Blue, Green}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much for spending your time answering; I learned a lot about visualization in Mathematica today.

Comment: @Massimo, my pleasure.